# Android can't find ActivityCompat methods even though it is installed

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

In my app, I use Android 6 specific premission requests for camera access. It used to work fine until my harddrive died and I had to resetup eclipse/android.

Now I get these errors

```
The method requestPermissions(MainActivity, String[], int) is undefined for the type ActivityCompat
The method checkSelfPermission(MainActivity, String) is undefined for the type ContextCompat
The method shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity, String) is undefined for the type ActivityCompat
```

When I try to compile even though `ActivityCompat` is recognized. I downloaded the Android Support Repository from the SDK manager and still had the `android-support-v4.jar` in my dependencies from svn but it doesn't seem to work.

All solutions that I have found so far point to include the library as library project from the sdk sources and then use that jar file in the dependencies but the folder does not exist in my sdk folder structure

```
<sdk>\extras\android\support
```

I have the following folder:

```
<sdk>\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support
```

But it doesn't include any library projects to include in eclipse.

How do I get those sources so I can import the support library into **eclipse** and refer to it from my project?

EDIT:

Here is the code that causes the errors:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(GalleryActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(GalleryActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(GalleryActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MainActivity.REQUEST_ALLOW_ACCESS_CAMERA_IMPORT);
    } else { 
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(GalleryActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MainActivity.REQUEST_ALLOW_ACCESS_CAMERA_IMPORT);
    }

} else {
    onTakeNewPhoto();
}
```

The sdk levels are deefined as follows in the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

My `project.properties` file

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
target=android-23
android.library.reference.1=Licensing
```

Comment: post the Activity code as well as build.gradle (app level)

Comment: edited my post to include the code. pretty standard code that used to work before. there is no build.crade file since im using eclipse

Comment: can u post your project.properties in eclipse project?

Comment: added project.properties to the question

Comment: Eclipse? Really in 2017? The ide is deprecated by the Android Team, take a time to switch to Android Studio and everything will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should update Android Sdk Tools, and Android Platform-tools, and Android Sdk Built-tools to the newest version

And then first try to import existing android project to your workspace, the path is :

```
<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
```

And then set the project above as library project. Lastly add that project as reference to your main project

Comment: Thats the problem, this folder does not exist in my SDK even though ive downloaded the Android Support Repository from the SDK manager

Comment: Try to download android support library, not repository

Comment: i cant find that option in my sdk manager. where is it supposed to be? under extras there is only android support repository and google repository which are both installed und up to date.

Comment: the official documentation says it should be the repository thats downloaded https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#download

Comment: ehh, it should be under extras folder, did you use proxy? Or maybe you should get newest android sdk installer, or you can install android studio which is newest sdk included.

Comment: I think I know the problem, in tools folder, have you already update Android Sdk Tools, and Android Platform-tools, and Android Sdk Built-tools to the newest version?

Comment: Yes, all of those are up to date. I just deleted and reinstalled the whole android sdk but the folder is still not there. Only the one mentioned in my question <sdk>\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support which does not contain library projects

Comment: in my sdk there is <Sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/24.1.1 Try copy one of the jar to your libs folder of your project. I'm sorry, i'm using eclipse in my office, but I suggest using android studio will give you great benefit, especially if you want to use push notification using FCM

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ive fixed it by donloading a newer android-support-v4.jar from github.